# Submitting an app to the App Store that uses BWToolkit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder, bwtoolkit

I'm currently using BWToolkit, does anyone know if there are any steps that need to be taken before submitting to the app store (as far as licensing)? Do I need to put any disclaimers anywhere etc? I know it's BSD licensed but I don't want to have my app rejected because I missed a simple legal step.. Any help?

Comment: Yes you need to put the acknowledgment. Hey, don't think of it as a stupid legal step; you should sincerely thank the developer. You're using the framework he created and generously open-sourced.  -- from another developer using the wonderful BWToolKit.

Comment: simple. not stupid. never said stupid. But thanks - looks pretty complicated, actually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not going to like this answer.

You will not be able to use the `BWToolkit.framework` **as-is**. Some of its classes rely on private APIs which Apple has strictly forbidden for apps that are submitted to the app store.

For example, the developer ran a tool called `class-dump` on the `AppKit.framework` Mach-O object and generated the .h files for 4 secret classes: `NSTokenAttachment` (an `NSTextAttachment` subclass), `NSTokenAttachmentCell` (an `NSTextAttachmentCell` subclass), `NSWindow (NSTimeMachineSupport)`, some additional methods on `NSWindow`, and `NSCustomView`.

I'm not that familiar with the inner workings of the framework, but depending on what classes you've made use of, **it may be possible to create a custom build of the framework from the source that doesn't include the private APIs**. Or, you could just include the source files for the classes you use in your project (provided of course that they don't rely on private APIs).

What particular classes did you make use of? If you used `BWSplitView`, you might look into using `RBSplitView`. (I talked to Rainer and have confirmed that there's no private APIs used in it, so you'd be okay).

Comment: wait- so if I used BWSplitView (I did) it will be rejected for using private APIs? That's ridiculous! Are you sure?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that NSGod is right.
You may want to read [this](http://bwalkin.lighthouseapp.com/projects/36323/tickets/72-mac-app-store-apps-rejected-due-to-the-use-of-bwtoolkit) and/or [that](http://byteproject.net/post/3016833303/bwtoolkit-1-2-5-w-o-private-api).